# Copy a static range on one sheet, and paste in a dynamic range in another sheet based on a single value in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have three parts to this problem.  I have a single cell with a Week number in Sheet1!A1.  I have a static range in Sheet1!B1:F1 that needs to be copied.  Then I need to paste the value in a dynamic range in Sheet2 offset by the week number for rows.  This is part of a larger macro I am writing for a sheet I use regularly, but I seem to have those parts down.  I may be either oversimplifying or oversimplifying but this is what I have currently.

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    Sheets(1).Range("B1:F1").Copy
    OffsetRange = Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value
    Sheets(2).Cells(1+OffsetRange,1).Paste
End Sub
```

When I run this, it either gives me a Runtime Error 9 or Runtime Error 438.

Anyone know whats causing these errors?  When I paste the range, does the cells object point towards the first cell of the copied range when I paste in at the location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as,

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPasteOffset()
    Dim OffsetRange As Long
    OffsetRange = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
    Worksheets(1).Range("B1:F1").Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets(2).Cells(1 + OffsetRange, 1)
End Sub
```

The [.Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821951.aspx) method is a member of Worksheet, not Range or Cells. You may have it confused with [.PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) which is a member of the Range object. In any event, it is unnecessary as a destination can be applied directly to the copy command.

Comment: Destination:= gives me "Expected: expression", and Destination = gives me "variable not defined"

Comment: Did you put an underscore after `.Copy _`? Did you rearrange the commands as I did?

Comment: I see the issue.  I didnt have a space between copy and the _.  Is there a way to include the destination of the copy to be paste as paste special values?  The original code doesn't include a paste action in there so I was curious how I could go about making this happen?

Comment: Well, there are a couple of ways (three come to mind off hand) but that isn't what you asked.

Comment: I know, new member, waiting 90 minutes to try and get this finished up is time consuming, oh well.  thanks for the help

Comment: Let me know... I've got my answer prepped.