# excel vba macro: copy column info to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this macro to copy data from 3 columns from workbook 'x' to workbook 'y' while not copying the hidden rows.

```
Sub GetDataDemo()
Const FileName As String = "EHS.xlsx"
Const SheetName As String = "PO"
FilePath = "C:\Users\DD\Desktop\"
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim this As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, ii As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If IsEmpty(Dir(FilePath & FileName)) Then

    MsgBox "The file " & FileName & " was not found", , "File Doesn't Exist"
Else

    Set this = ActiveSheet

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & FileName)

    With wb.Worksheets(SheetName).Range("Y:AA")

        ii = 3
        For i = 3 To 500

            If Not .Rows(i).Hidden Then

                .Cells(i).Copy
                this.Range("P:R").Cells(ii).Paste
                ii = ii + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End If

ActiveWindow.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I keep getting the Automation error (Error 440) near the line:

```
this.Range("P:R").Cells(ii).Paste
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to copy & paste the visible cells/rows in bulk.

```
With wb.Worksheets(SheetName).Range("Y3:AA500")
    on error resume next
    .SpecialCells(xlcelltypevisible).Copy this.Range("P3")
    on error goto 0
End With
```

.Paste is a member of Worksheet, not of Range or Cells.

`this` is a reserved name; it is not considered 'best practice' to reuse reserved names as vars.

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `.SpecialCells(xlcelltypevisible).Copy this.Range("P3")`?

Comment: @SJR - doesn't that do the same thing?

Comment: @BruceWayne - `Paste` isn't a method for a `Range` object.  (It's `Worksheet.Paste` or `Range.PasteSpecial`.)

Comment: @SJR, thank you for catching that. Nothing like providing a non-working rewrite of non-working  code!

Comment: Easily done. Never made much sense to me that you can't paste to a range.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350009/copy-a-static-range-on-one-sheet-and-paste-in-a-dynamic-range-in-another-sheet/43350141#43350141) for more information.

Comment: Where would I put this new code? I am very new to VBA.

Comment: It would replace the code starting with `With wb.Worksheets(SheetName).Range("Y:AA")` and ending with `End With`.

Comment: Great thanks Jeeped it works! The only problem is now I get this error: 'run time error 438 object doesn't support this property or method'  near this line 
    ActiveWindow.ScreenUpdating = True

Comment: Well, I just ran the code and it works for me. I will admit to being confused by your conflicting statements that *'it works'* and *'now I get this error'* though.